# How To Copy Or Move Folders From One Folder To Another Based On A List In Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, directory, subdirectory

I have a list of 346 folders in Excel, that refers to 346 folders out of 10.000 total folders in the working directory.

I want to copy/move only the specified 346 folders (out of 10.000) to a new folder.

Please note that the inquiry refers to **folders** not files.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could just go ahead and call OS functions from VBA, and just use the standard `copy` function:

```vb
Sub test()
  Dim command As String
  command = "copy c:\test.txt c:\test1.txt"
  Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K " & command, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Then you can go ahead and make the command string for each entry.

Note that the `cmd.exe` needs to be included here, `Shell(...)` expects an executable file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just a clarification : I want to copy some folders not files. I see in your code a mention in .txt (files) not folders. How could I adapt the code to target the listed folders? Thank you.

Comment: However you would copy any given folder from the command line. Try xcopy: ```xcopy C:\source_folder D:\destination_folder\```

Comment: Very useful thanks. If the source folder contains sub-folders which contain the desired sub-folders will this work?

Comment: Work on crafting the specific command you want to execute for a single folder on the command line first, and adapt the VBA code above to use that for all of them. I gave a very short example on purpose, as you would need to tweak it for your needs anyway (Read all entries, iterate over them and call the copy command for each).

To use xcopy was only a suggestion; you can see the specific options available by typing `xcopy /?`

Comment: Thank you very much. I will lo9k into it and possibly come back with any questions.